# Create Dictionary from Penn Treebank Corpus sample from NLTK?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, nltk, corpus

I know that the Treebank corpus is already tagged, but unlike the Brown corpus, I can't figure out how to get a dictionary of tags. For instance,

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> wordcounts = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(brown.tagged_words())
```

This doesn't work on the Treebank corpus?

Comment: which treebank? if you meant penn treebank, then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Alvations/NLTK_cheatsheet/CorporaReaders#Penn_Tree_Bank

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work with the treebank corpus? It has a `tagged_words()` method, and it works exactly like `brown.tagged_words()`. If it doesn't work for you, your error is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import treebank
>>> from nltk import ConditionalFreqDist as cfd
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> treebank_tagged_words = list(chain(*list(chain(*[[tree.pos() for tree in treebank.parsed_sents(pf)] for pf in treebank.fileids()]))))
>>> wordcounts = cfd(treebank_tagged_words)
>>> treebank_tagged_words[0]
(u'Pierre', u'NNP')
>>> wordcounts[u'Pierre']
FreqDist({u'NNP': 1})
>>> treebank_tagged_words[100]
(u'asbestos', u'NN')
>>> wordcounts[u'asbestos']
FreqDist({u'NN': 11})
```

For more details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Alvations/NLTK_cheatsheet/CorporaReaders#Penn_Tree_Bank

See also: [Is there a way of avoiding so many list(chain(*list_of_list))?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878953/is-there-a-way-of-avoiding-so-many-listchainlist-of-list)

---

Note that there are only 3000+ sentences from the Penn Treebank sample from NLTK, the brown corpus has 50,000 sentences.

To split the sentences up into training and test set:

```
from nltk.corpus import treebank
from nltk import ConditionalFreqDist as cfd
from itertools import chain

treebank_tagged_sents = list(chain(*[[tree.pos() for tree in treebank.parsed_sents(pf)] for pf in treebank.fileids()]))


total_len = len(treebank_tagged_sents)
train_len = int(90 * total_len /100)

train_set = treebank_tagged_sents[:train_len]
print len(train_set)
train_treebank_tagged_words = cfd(chain(*train_set))

test_set = treebank_tagged_sents[train_len:]
print len(test_set)
test_treebank_tagged_words = cfd(chain(*test_set))
```

If you're going to use brown corpus (that does not contain parsed sentence), you can used the `tagged_sent()`:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents()
>>> len(brown_tagged_sents)
57340
>>> brown_tagged_sents[0]
[(u'The', u'AT'), (u'Fulton', u'NP-TL'), (u'County', u'NN-TL'), (u'Grand', u'JJ-TL'), (u'Jury', u'NN-TL'), (u'said', u'VBD'), (u'Friday', u'NR'), (u'an', u'AT'), (u'investigation', u'NN'), (u'of', u'IN'), (u"Atlanta's", u'NP$'), (u'recent', u'JJ'), (u'primary', u'NN'), (u'election', u'NN'), (u'produced', u'VBD'), (u'``', u'``'), (u'no', u'AT'), (u'evidence', u'NN'), (u"''", u"''"), (u'that', u'CS'), (u'any', u'DTI'), (u'irregularities', u'NNS'), (u'took', u'VBD'), (u'place', u'NN'), (u'.', u'.')]
>>> total_len = len(brown_tagged_sents)
>>> train_len = int(90 * total_len/100)
>>> train_set = brown_tagged_sents[:train_len]
>>> train_brown_tagged_words = cfd(chain(*train_set))
>>> train_brown_tagged_words['asbestos']
FreqDist({u'NN': 1})
```

---

As @alexis noted, unless you're splitting the corpus at sentence level. The `tagged_words()` function also exist in the Penn Treebank API in NLTK:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import treebank
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown

>>> treebank.tagged_words()
[(u'Pierre', u'NNP'), (u'Vinken', u'NNP'), ...]
>>> brown.tagged_words()
[(u'The', u'AT'), (u'Fulton', u'NP-TL'), ...]

>>> type(treebank.tagged_words())
<class 'nltk.corpus.reader.util.ConcatenatedCorpusView'>
>>> type(brown.tagged_words())
<class 'nltk.corpus.reader.util.ConcatenatedCorpusView'>

>>> from nltk import ConditionalFreqDist as cfd
>>> cfd(brown.tagged_words())
<ConditionalFreqDist with 56057 conditions>
>>> cfd(treebank.tagged_words())
<ConditionalFreqDist with 12408 conditions>
```

Comment: I hate to open up another question, so I'm going to just comment here: Is there a way to collect all tagged words up until a certain tagged_sents position? I want to create a partial dictionary, and when I add a limit on tagged_words it is not the same size limit as I want. For instance: wordcounts = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist((w, t) for w, t in brown.tagged_words(tagset="universal")) -- I want this to end at tagged_sents()[:10000] but, of course, if I add [:something] it stops at the tagged_words position

Comment: @Alvas, drop the calls to `list`. You're defeating the whole point of iterators.

Comment: @alvas Thanks for the update, I'm going to try and do this with the Brown because of the big size difference. Its pretty much the same code, but substitute brown for treebank?

Comment: @alvas AttributeError: 'CategorizedTaggedCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'parsed_sents'

Comment: @nate, brown corpus doesn't have `parsed_sents` use `tagged_sents` instead.